# error msg if required input empty

Tags: jquery

I've been looking around for a solution to this, but can't seem to find any examples that work for me. Here's what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("form#submit").submit(function() {
      // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
      var user_email     = $('#user_email').attr('value');
      var mobile     = $('#mobile').attr('value');
      var id_country     = $('#id_country').attr('value');
      var id_target     = $('#id_target').attr('value');    
      var id = $('#id').attr('value'); 

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "user_email="+ user_email + "&mobile=" + mobile + "&id_country=" +
        id_country + "&id_target=" + id_target + "&id=" + id,
        success: function(){
            $('form#submit');
            //$('form#submit :input').val("");
            $('div.success').fadeIn("slow")
            $('div.success').fadeOut("slow");
          }
       });
      return false;
   });
});
```

When I submit the form, data insert to the database successfully. I need div.error if required input empty !!!
How can I edit my code to fill all required field with class="required" ????

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for client side validation to validate if the fields entered are not empty? And then create an error message if it is?

Comment: thanks for answer I add $("form#submit").validate(); for my code, I get error msg if field empty or email not valid in the same time I get success msg and data updated in my database !!!! How can I use If statement to check before submit and where to use it in my code .... I'm new with jquery please help

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is a very well develop jquery validation tool for client side validation (before your ajax call).

If you are looking to verify if the fields are empty, you can look at the example [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)
You can provide specific messages for each field, or a generic message for all of them.

This also seems to be an introduction which is very suitable for what you want to do: http://elegantcode.com/2009/09/27/playing-with-jquery-validation-library/

It also allows you to make sure your user_email field is a proper email address

Try using the validate function like this

```
    $("#submit").validate({
        rules : {
          user_email: {
              required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          user_email: {
            required: "This field is required"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form)   {
           // Put your ajax call in here                
        }                
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please I need to modify my code I have a lot of examples put I can't join it with my code .... help please